# Can you import differently-structured data into a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: json, reactjs, database, postgresql, react-native

I hope I phrased that correctly.

From my understanding, SQL data must follow strict schema formats

e.g.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Jesus",
  "middleName": "H.",
  "lastName": "Christ"
}
```

Data I import into a SQL database would all have to follow this format, right? To fit into a pre-defined SQL Schema?

---

I ask because a startup hired me to fix their app.  It had been using `GraphCool` for it's data, but that service shut down.

They exported all their data and gave me the files containing all of it.

To migrate the data that was once in `GraphCool` to `Prisma 2`, it is first required that I import the data into PostgreSQL.

The data are in a few, very large files.  And it doesn't follow a structure.

For example, in the beginning of one of the files, the data is structured like so:

```
{
  {
    "valueType": "nodes",
    "values": [
      {
        "tagName": "etc",
        "updatedAt": "etc",
        "_typeName":"etc",
        "id":"etc",
        "createdAt":"etc"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "etc",
        "updatedAt": "etc",
        "_typeName":"etc",
        "id":"etc",
        "createdAt":"etc"
      },
      { ... }
```

..but later on, in the same file, the structure changes to a convoluted mess:

```
{
  "tagName":"etc",
  "updatedAt":"etc",
  "_typeName":"etc",
  "id":"etc",
  "createdAt":"etc"
},
{
  "updatedAt":"etc",
  "_typeName":"etc",
  "data": {
    "value": [
      {
        "form_1": {
          "timestamp":"etc",
          "model": {
            "type":"etc",
            "key":"etc",
            "content": {
              "text":"etc",
              "smallKey":"etc",
              "listText":"etc"
            },
...
```

Is there a way to import large chunks of data, regardless of structure, into a PostreSQL database?

Comment: Before thinking about how to _import_ the data, you need to think about how you want to _use_ the data. If you're going to use it with a particular tool, what structure does that tool require / expect? If you're going to query it on particular aspects, what are they? Is that "messy" data something you need to be able to query based on, or can it be treated as a single blob displayed to the user unprocessed? At one extreme, you could just import the whole data as a single string of text in a single column of a single table; but that's unlikely to be useful.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  My understanding of this may not be at the level it needs to be, for this task.  Their app had many users, and the hosting service is gone, and so the app is broken.  I thought this would merely be a matter of giving their data to a new hosting service, and pointing the app (react-native) to the new service.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you may be out of your depth. You're not moving between _hosting services_ - that would imply you're using the same technologies in both places, and just paying a different company for the servers; it sounds like what's happening is that you're moving between _hosted applications_, which have the same purpose, but different ways of working. Unless the new service has an importer for the old service's export format, *and* a compatible API for whatever your app actually does with this data, you're going to need to spend some time understanding what the data _means_.

Comment: The switch is from GraphCool to Prisma 2.  So... no, it doesn't have the convenient things you mentioned.  Thanks for the comment, I will spend time with this and return to this post with updates or (likely, more help) unless a new SO post is needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I would not just throw each array element into a `jsonb` column,

Rather, define a table that has proper columns for all the frequent and important attributes, and a `jsonb` for the rest:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
   pkey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   updatedat timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
   typename text NOT NULL,
   tagname text,
   createdat timestamp with time zone,
   extra_junk jsonb
);
```

That will allow you to retain the convoluted JSON mess (minus the normal attributes, because data duplication is bad), while you have normal columns for the frequent attributes, particularly those that you want to use in SQL statements.

If none of the attributes are important for your database processing, you can of course throw the whole array element in a `jsonb`. "Important" in this context are attributes that are used in queries, constraints and so on. If you know the SQL statements, you can figure those out. Strive to use JSON only for those parts that are just "payload" for the database.

Comment: Interesting.  So, do I manually look at the data, make a list of all the most frequently-occurring attributes, write columns for each of them and then jsonb the rest?

Seems possible that I may end up not making columns for attributes that are important

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear.  Your answer coincides with IMSoPs comment well.  I am parsing through the app's code now.  I will update this post with my findings and/or if I need help again.  Thank you

Comment: Hey Laurenz.  I found all the SQL statements along with the relevant attributes.  It's still not clear to me, cuz there's Models but it seems like the query/mutation statements (graphql) don't necessarily follow the exact model structure.  I'm going through the data files manually now, adding new-lines and indentation so I can understand the structure of tthe data better.  Is this a good idea or am I wasting time?

Comment: It's also not clear whether I need just one schema table, or multiple

Comment: @Cin88 The project you have taken on is part translation (into a completely new data structure) and part rewrite (so that the application works with the new data structure). In order for that project to be successful, you need to have a good understanding of what the data means *and* how the application uses it - not just at the level of "field A is used by function B", but "field A represents X in the real world, and the application uses it to achieve business purpose Y". If you want to get the application working without that, you need to find a technology much closer to the original.

Comment: I see. The data files are one-line of a huge JSON field.  I'm doing the labor of splitting new-lines and indentation so I can understand what the data means.  As for finding a technology closer to the original.. as far as I researched, it looks like GraphCool >>> Prisma2 is the way to go.  But I'm shocked that I haven't found more cases of people attempting to switch from GraphCool, as it had thousands of users.

I'll do more research on that front, just in case Prisma2 is not the answer.  Do you have any familiarity with GraphCool and what may be similar?